# Game unresponsive

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Normally, I'd say the process stopped or something and just revert from a previous save, but this error is a little different. The cursor isn't frozen and sound is still playing. The interface responds to a point, but it refuses to advance.

There are still sound responses when I try to interact with the interface (beeps when I click to reload) and tooltips still appear when I hover over an icon. Camera rotation still works as well. However, gameplay does not advance and it's stuck on my last soldier's turn.

This is also not a one-time occurence, I have encountered this error in the past. However, I'm not sure how to reproduce it, although based on the last event, it happened when I uncovered an enemy on my turn.

NOTE (2013/03/22 5:14 CST): Happened again, although this time was with trying to get a soldier into Overwatch.

Comment: Hmm... if this downvote means that I've shown no research effort, go ahead and post the solution. 'Cause I haven't found a thing.

Comment: I've also had this problem. no known cure. Really annoying when you're close to winning a campaign, I didn't save for hours... :(

Answer (score 1):

This is a known (I hope!) bug at the time of writing. There's not much to do currently except wait for a patch. The bug is rare and seems to strike me randomly, and I have not been able to reproduce the error. The few times it's happened I've been forced to kill the process and load a save-game.

Answer (score 0):

If you're playing on the Steam version, it could be the Steam Overlay interfering. I had something similar on my first ever mission. It was pretty annoying!

To fix it, just go in and out of the Steam Overlay a few times (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>).